# Integrating $\frac{\int_0^{\sqrt\pi} 3\sqrt\theta\sin(\theta^2)\,d\theta}{\sqrt\pi-0}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I've come across [this](https://apcentral.collegeboard.org/pdf/ap19-frq-calculus-bc.pdf)  question (2b.) when studying for AP Calculus BC.

$$\frac{\int_0^{\sqrt\pi} 3\sqrt\theta\sin(\theta^2)\,d\theta}{\sqrt\pi-0}$$

I did the following, but I am stuck on how to reduce it from the sin and the radical.

$$\frac{3}{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt\pi} \sqrt\theta\sin(\theta^2)\,d\theta$$

$$\frac{3}{2\sqrt\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin(u)}{\sqrt[4]u}\,du$$ $$u=\theta^2, du = 2\theta\,d\theta$$

I also tried a partial integration route (plus another sub) which left me with
$$-\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\pi\sqrt[4]{x^3}\cos(x)\,dx$$

Same issue, that I can't simplify the radical and trig function together.

Any ideas? You're also welcome to look at the problem and see if there is another approach.

Btw, I don't see any elementary solutions on WolframAlpha, so I don't know if it's possible to solve by hand.

Comment: The problem in your link is a polar integral.  Integrate $r^2/2$ instead of $r$.

Comment: Maple gives an answer for the integral you have stated in terms of the Lommel s function....... whatever that is :)  I would say this almost certainly means there is no simple solution.

Comment: @B.Goddard I would love to, but that's not the question. Part a is finding the area in which I integrate $r^2/2$ for a clean answer of $9\pi/8$. However, part b is to find the average distance to the curve from the origin which is integrating $r/(b-a)$.

Comment: @Nathan29006781 Answer can be reduced to generalized hypergeometric function ${}_1F_{2}$ or incomplete Gamma function (as in Wolfram Alpha). What do you mean by "solve by hand": obtain special function representation of answer? I believe, knowing specific form of an answer you can represent integral in form corresponding to answer, but if it is useful? Why is this answer better than original integral form?

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu By "solve by hand", I mean basic functions like algebraic+trig+exponential. I am looking for the decimal representation of the answer. I know it is roughly 1.5799, but I was hoping there was a good way to get the answer other than a calculator

Comment: I believe, answer cannot be reduced to closed-form, that's why these functions are called special, only some specific values of these functions can be represented in closed-form. Answer to your problem can be represented also in the form of infinite power series. For obtaining decimal representation, you can use numerical integration.  About getting answer with calculator: even obtaining decimal representation of sin(1) requires using calculator.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick preface, this is simply the *best* answer I can give. This is most likely not the most efficient method to achieve the answer shown, but this is just the way I did it. Note that if you put the expression in WolframAlpha, it will spit out the same hypergeometric function. Since you wanted a way to get the answer with a basic calculator or by hand, just sum up the first 20 terms or so, and you'll get a pretty solid approximation (the series converges rather quickly). I personally prefer the summation notation, so here is the derivation:

$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\sqrt{\pi}3\sqrt{\theta}\sin\left(\theta^2\right)d\theta$$
$$u=\sqrt{\theta},\ du=\frac{d\theta}{2\sqrt{\theta}},\ d\theta=2\sqrt{\theta}du$$
$$=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt[4]{\pi}}3u^{2}\sin\left(u^{4}\right)du$$
$$v=u^3,\ dv=3u^2du$$
$$=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\pi^{\frac{3}{4}}}\sin\left(v\sqrt[3]{v}\right)dv$$
$$=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\pi^{\frac{3}{4}}}\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}\left(v\sqrt[3]{v}\right)^{2n+1}}{\left(2n+1\right)!}dv$$
$$Using\ Fubini\text{'}s\ Theorem,\ Switch\ the\ Order\ of\ Summation$$
$$=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\left(2n+1\right)!}\int_{0}^{\pi^{\frac{3}{4}}}v^{\frac{8n+4}{3}}dv$$
$$=6\pi^{\frac{5}{4}}\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}\pi^{2n}}{\left(8n+7\right)\left(2n+1\right)!}$$
$$We\ can\ now\ stop\ if\ you\ want\ a\ Real\ Answer,$$
$$But\ I\ personally\ like\ this\ simplification\ more:$$
$$=\frac{6\pi\sqrt[4]{\pi}}{i\pi}\sum_{n\in\{\mathrm{odd}\}}\frac{\left(i\pi\right)^{n}}{\left(n+3\right)n!}$$
$$=-6i\sqrt[4]{\pi}\sum_{n\in\{\mathrm{odd}\}}\frac{\left(i\pi\right)^{n}}{\left(n+3\right)n!}$$